# Promise never receives state updates from outside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

### Backstory so this makes more sense

I have a multidimensional array holding start and end times of parts of a video that i want to play. I loop over these start and end times, playing the video then waiting for it to reach the end time (in a promise), at that point I can resolve the promise and the next start and end times can be played.

The part of this code that doesn't work, is inside the promise I have an if statement that pretty much continuously checks my `isPlayingClips` state, if it turns to false, it should resolve the promise early and return "cancelled". I see the state updating inside my useEffect, but the state inside the promise never updates.

### Example

This is my whole useEffect that has the `isPlayingClips` state as a dependecy:

```
const [isPlayingClips, setIsPlayingClips] = useState<boolean>(false); 

useEffect(() => {
    // This logs the correct updates, it just isn't reflected inside the promise
    console.log("isPlayingClips updated:", isPlayingClips);

    async function playClips() {
      // This return an array looking like: [[57.98, 62.98], [114.96, 119.96]]
      let clips = getAllClips();

      for (let i = 0, n = clips.length; i < n; ++i) {
        // Clip start and end times
        let start = clips[i][0];
        let end = clips[i][1];

        // Skip to start of clip and play
        updateVideoTime(start);
        player.play();

        // Play clip until we reach `end` or playing is cancelled.
        let cp = await new Promise((resolve) => {
          // isPlayingClips is always true, which is the value it is when this promise is created/run, but never updates to false when it does in the useEffect
          const u = () => {
            console.log(player.currentTime, end, isPlayingClips);

            // If isPlayingClips state changes to false resolve promise early
            if (!isPlayingClips) {
              console.log("CANCELLING PLAYING CLIPS");
              player.removeEventListener("timeupdate", u);
              resolve("cancelled");
            }

            // When we reach end time resolve promise
            if (player.currentTime >= end) {
              player.pause();
              player.removeEventListener("timeupdate", u);

              resolve("finished");
            }
          };

          player.addEventListener("timeupdate", u);
        });

        // If promise above was cancelled, return as to not continue playing clips.
        if (cp == "cancelled") return;
      }
    }

    if (isPlayingClips) {
      playClips();
    } else {
      player.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlayingClips]);
```

## The question

Am I doing something wrong? Why are the state changes never reflected from within the promise?

Comment: yes, the value of `isPlayingClips` will only ever be the value it is at the time of the method call. Meaning, if it updates, a new async method is constructed and called with the new `isPlayingClips`

Comment: @DerekPollard Thanks for the reply. How am I suppose to get this functionality working, I need some sort of way to cancel the promise (resolve it early) when the state changes to false. Is there any sort of workaround/different way of doing this you can think of?

Comment: I _believe_ you can use a ref `useRef` and its value should reflect the correct current value. Of course, you'd probably want to use this in-tandem with useState since you're probably relying on useState for some UI

Comment: but that's a bit hacky. Honestly, without seeing the full implementation, I'm not sure. For sure I'd probably introduce a way to cancel the promise and probably extract out a factory to handle the `playClips` bit that returns a cancellable promise which I can call in the return of the `useEffect`

Comment: @DerekPollard you sexy genious it worked, i dont mind its a tiny bit hacky, but it works! I just set an is-playing-clips attribute on the player

Comment: Lol, glad I could help you!

Comment: @DerekPollard Thanks again, the ratio of time I spent working on a problem and time spend someone solving my issue has never been shorter, you instantly fixed this for me. I will never forget